# how do capture drop down menu value in a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using a piece of code within a form for a drop down list that is populated by a directory on a web site:

```
  <select name="mydrop" id="mydrop">
  <option value="" selected="selected">--a--</option>
    <?php 
            foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename){
            $filename = basename($filename);
            echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
        }
?>

</select>
```

I have two text boxes and a text area inputting. When I action my php file all of the data values are there but not from this drop down menu. Any ideas why?

I use:

```
$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$table=$_POST['table'];
$image=$_GET['mydrop']; //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Have you also closed the select box? The `</select>` is missing.

Comment: Should i show the full form code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why do you use `$_POST` for everything else but `$_GET` for the `<select>`? If the form is submitted via POST, `mydrop` should also be in `$_POST`.

This line:

```
$image=$_GET['mydrop']; //Doesn't work
```

should probably be this:

```
$image = $_POST['mydrop'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `value` attribute on each `<option>` needs to be filled in. That is what is `POST`ed for the form.
You're using `$image=$_GET['mydrop'];`, but it should be `$image=$_POST['mydrop'];`. `$_GET` is for URL parameters, such as `?foo=bar` at the end of a URL. `$_GET['foo']` would be `bar`.

Comment: But the options are determined by how many files are in the directory this number could change

Comment: @Mike yet you will receive the selected option thru POST, as every other field in the form.